# Computing sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^k}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

## Summation Question

- What is the value of:
  $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^k}{k!}$$

***thanks***

Comment: That just means $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{3^k}{k!}$$ Do you know about Taylor series? Think about that and the exponential function...

Comment: Recall that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that
$$e^x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ 
Therefore
$$e^3=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{n!}$$